# grails missingmethodexception with maven build and run on tomcat (standalone tomcat server)

Tags: maven, tomcat, grails

i have a rather weired problem. my grails application runs just fine when i run from the ide (sts). but when i do a maven build and deploy it to a standalone webserver, i get missingMethodExceptions when i try to access the dynamic finders on the domain object. this application contain both java domain objects and grails domain objects. and i get this error when i try to access .findBy() or get(). funny thing is when i run fom rht eide (run-app) it works fine. Any ideas on what i am doing wrong? by the way i am using grails 2.2.3 but i also tried grails 2.2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue should be with the maven build that you are doing. Try grails war ROOT.war to create the build.